# Adjacent colors in swift

Tags: swift, colors, uicolor

I'm using an API which returns images based on their color. I send a hex value, i.e. `FF0000` and it returns images with that red color.

However, the API is rather too specific. For the above color for instance, I'd want to return all red stuff, not just that specific red.

Luckily the API allows a union of colors FF0000u0000FF is pure red and blue.

So what I need to do create an array of colors which surround the main color, so that I can pass it to the API,

How would I do this in Swift?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but I've done similar things by transforming the RGB into HSB and then searching in the H dimension.

Answer (score 0):

There are well over 16 million colours available in that colour space so I don't think that creating an array will be practical as there could easily be hundreds of thousands of 'reds' to add to that array. A better approach would be to adapt the api to compare a range of values of each separate channel so rather than red equating to FF0000, you would say that 'red' is any colour where the red channel is greater than 88 (HEX) and the other channels are less than 66 (HEX) for instance. It's a complex task that you're trying to achieve so it won't be a trivial job to solve it. If you share some code or a link to the API, someone may be able to give you more specific help.